# std::shared_mutex recursive protection by thread_local storage

Tags: c++

The idea is to use the `std::shared_mutex` all right, but protect deadlocks in case that `std::shared_mutex::lock()` for exclusive access is called by the same thread.

For example:

```
std::shared_mutex m;
void f2()
{
  m.lock();
}
void f1()
{
   m.lock();
   f2();
}
```

`f1()` would lock because std::shared_mutex cannot be called recursively. For this I have two options:
Either to use my own [tlock](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1186797/tlock-Any-Cplusplus-object-read-write-thread-safe) of read-write mutex which uses Windows Mutex which supports recursive locking, or to use this sort of a locking function based on a `thread_local` variable:

```
thread_local bool LockedStuff = 0;
void Lock(std::function<...> f)
{
    if (LockedStuff)
        {
         f(...);
         return;
        }
    LockedStuff = 1;
    m.lock();
    f(...);
    m.unlock();
    LockedLinks = 0;
}
```

The question is, is there anything I'm missing that can go wrong with the above implementation? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Needed a while until I got your question. ;-) So, you are looking for a _shared recursive mutex_, aren't you? I found [SO: A shared recursive mutex in standard C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36624355/7478597).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You effectively have two locks that way, one of them per-thread, one per process. Your other approach does the opposite: lock only between threads. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: Why do you have a function, `f2`, that just takes a lock and does nothing else?  In any case, this feels like you have a small (but solvable) design problem that doesn't require a special template trick.

Comment: I also just noticed you are using *shared*_mutex.  Not sure if that matters, but do you actually need a shared mutex, or do you really just want to share a std::mutex between threads (which is the normal pattern).

Comment: @selbie yes I want a shared mutex because this would be for read/write locking scenarios. The problem is that more complex functions that need an exclusive lock might call one another.

Answer (score 0):

That you don't RAII your mutex and thread local variable. If exception is called inside the function your mutex will be forever locked.